# Constrain values in matlab

Tags: matlab, constraints

If i have a simple array in matlab, say:

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0]
```

How do i constrain the values in that array (if for example i want the maximum value to be 1, so to get to:

```
a = [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
```

What would be the simplest, most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a(a>1) = 1;
```

This would do what you're asking... you can follow the same pattern for other constraints.

Edit: commenter is correct, fixed.

Comment: This is almost the right answer, but it should be `a(a>1) = 1;`

Answer (score 3):

```
a > 0
```

or

```
min(a, 1)
```

(Tested in Octave.)

Comment: you mean an if-loop that tests for a > 0? Because i would prefer a way to do this without a loop. There has to be a way to do this in matlab without a loop..

Comment: @Samuel: no, just the expression `a > 0`.

Comment: `a>0` returns a logical index, not a new matrix. You can use the logical index to set the appropriate elements in a to some value.

Comment: @tmpearce: ah. In Octave, it returns a matrix of zeros and ones. Does my `min`-based solution work in Matlab?

Comment: I believe so - and your `a<0` as a logical index can be cast to zeros and ones - but using logical indexing "proper" lets you modify the code much easier, for example to be between to value or pretty much anything else.  Both of your usages specifically work in a limited number of cases - elegant and fast but not as easily modified.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
arrayfun(@(x) min(1,x),a)
```

For the max value and substitute max(val,x) for the min.

Comment: Wild overkill. An abuse of arrayfun to do something for which min(a,1) is already vectorized to do. Worse, for vectors of significant length, it is 1000 times slower than simply using min directly!

Comment: Agreed, I got a little carried away in wanting to make it fit any need, but missed out on fulfilling what was asked!